# Split a line in 2 pieces

Tags: regex, perl

Can anyone help me with a regex to split this

```
BRANDT RAYMOND W & C M TRS 970 CASTLE HILL RD, REDWOOD CITY, CA 94061
```

I want `$1 = BRANDT RAYMOND W & C M TRS 970` and `$2 = CASTLE HILL RD, REDWOOD CITY, CA 94061`

I don't know how to put that condition that the first match should end with a digit, then a white space and the second match will start with a 'C'

Comment: You have enough reputation to vote: http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
my $line = 'BRANDT RAYMOND W & C M TRS 970 CASTLE HILL RD, REDWOOD CITY, CA 94061';

$line =~ /(.*?\d)\s(C.*)/;

print "$1\n$2\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) with lookaround assertions:

```perl
my ( $first, $second ) = split /(?<=\d)\s+(?=C)/, $string, 2;
```

This will consume the whitespace which is presumably unwanted.